# Does the density of water affect the speed of sea waves?

Tags: waves, water, speed, density

In the case of light waves, the denser the matter, the more slowly they propagate. Do the water waves behave identically?

Comment: Sure. The behaviour is related, among other parameters, to the speed of sound in water.

Answer (score 1):

The speed is $\sqrt{K_s/\rho}$, $K_s$ the bulk modulus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes water waves do.  The more dense the liquid the slower the waves will propagate for a given disturbance.  The density is the mass/volume. Hence a more dense liquid has more mass per unit volume making it more difficult to generate waves of a given size and speed.